# Why can't an inductor be used in a half wave rectifier?

Tags: dc, filter, inductor, rectifier

I am studying filter circuits and there I spotted one sentence as disadvantage of an inductor filter,

> Inductor filter cannot be used in half wave rectifier .

Why?

I request simple answer because I don't know much about electronics.

Comment: I believe the disadvantage has to do with saturation, but using an inductor with an air gap would help with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't (or rather "shouldn't") be used in a half wave rectifier circuit because there is no sensible path for the stored energy it has accumulated (in its magnetic field) to efficiently dissipate when the diode becomes reverse biased.

Normal half wave rectifier with no series inductor: -

[image]

Adding 100 mH series inductor and parasitic capacitance of 10 pF (a reasonable value): -

[image]

Circuit simulated: -

[image]

Comment: The answer is more subtle than it seems. I too did a simulation, but noticed the inductor current is always discontinuous. I had sort of assumed that a big enough inductor value would force it to be continuous, the diode freewheeling the current on the -ve half cycle. But no. The mean zero voltage out of V1, less the diode drop, is not enough voltage to get a net DC current flowing in the inductor. So there's always nasty ringing between the inductance and the parasitic C on its input when the diode stops conducting. Full wave gives a net +ve voltage.

Comment: @Neil_UK I think if you use a capacitor (like the 10pF) where I did or, put some capacitance across the diode it becomes a tad clearer but, the bottom line is why bother with a half wave rectifier (and its associated problems when used with an inductor) when you can use a FW bridge. It's a moot point really. The bridge won't be perfect of course (but better).

Comment: My ringing was very fast and was about to add C2 when I saw your answer so stopped bothering. I originally thought the reason was economic, you would have to use an impractically large inductor to get continuous current. However as you cannot get continuous current at any inductor value, adding one does exactly nothing for the output ripple on C1, there is literally no point in adding it. With a FW bridge, it's useful. It's not so much that the stored energy has nowhere to go as the energy at current stopping is small, and one could add a snubber if the inductor was otherwise useful.

Comment: A free-wheeling diode might help but than: why would we want to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When some conditions are [fulfilled](https://be1lib.org/book/5778862/9fd0d1) or [this](https://ceng.tu.edu.iq/eed/images/PE_lect7.compressed.pdf), this circuit can be used.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What conditions? What am I looking at? Why are there two diodes?

Comment: D1 is the rectifiyng diode. D2 is the "freewheel" diode for the inductor. These circuits (called Px, PDx or Sx) were used for controlling "motors" with SCR (variable rpm and very efficient electronic braking). The only flaw is that inductor ... But only for the "old" guy as me ... And they had also an advantage ... when making a "short" at output load. They were used, for years, in "metallurgy" as driving "rolling mill" ... For conditions of use ... one must review very "old" "power electronics".